# passing array of pointers to a function

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I have the following part of code:

```
int res[10] = {-1, 2,-2,-4,-5,-6, 0, 0, 9,-10};

int* resP[10];
for(int i=0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
    resP[i] = res+i;
}
int score;
apply(0, resP, 10, &score);
```

apply signature looks like this (**I'm not allowed to change it**):

```
void apply(int, int* [], int, int*);
```

but my function call above doesn't work because the second parameter is of the wrong type and I don't understand why.

Comment: i think you need to supply the rest of the code you have not provided anything about `com` or `score`

Comment: I don't understand how the function call effects the loop.

Comment: Why are you assigning `res + i - 1` to `resP`s? First assignment would be then `res - 1` which is out of bounds. Rest of the code seems correct to me.

Comment: and score has no inportance here, it can be anything, it has nothing to do with the problem

Comment: OP's not allowed to change that

Comment: what's your compiler and error you're getting?

Comment: `passing argument 2 of 'apply' from incompatible pointer type`

Comment: If what I've commented doesn't help, you'll have to show us your code, because as far as we can see, it is alright the way it is, other than; it does not have a `main`, signature of `apply` is placed after the call to it and things like that, which we've assumed to be correct. Show us the code, maybe they aren't.

Comment: `but my function call above doesn't work` What does that mean. Did you get any error/warning. If yes, then include it in your question

Answer (score 4):

The code is compiled successfuly

```
#include <stdio.h>

void apply(int _1, int* _2[], int _3, int* _4){}

int main(void) 
{
    int res[10] = {-1, 2,-2,-4,-5,-6, 0, 0, 9,-10};

    int* resP[10];

    for( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ )
    {
        resP[i] = res+i-1;
    }

    int score;

    apply(0, resP, 10, &score); 
}
```

The second argument has suitable type. So the problem somewhere else. Though the assignment statement in the loop is wrong. You may not access memory before the first element of the array. That is pointer resP[0] is not valid.

I do not see the relation between "my function call above doesn't work" and  "the second parameter is of the wrong type". You did not say what you mean by  "my function call above doesn't work".

Comment: I think you're right. OP hasn't shown exact error he is getting.

Comment: @Don't You Worry Child  I can use only the information he provided.:)

Comment: It would be better if there was a prototype separate from the definition, and without parameter names as in OP, so that it'd be 1:1, but this works good enough.

Comment: @mafso  A comment may not be so large.:)

Answer (score 2):

Your code compiles fine for me. But there is another problem:

```
for(int i=0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
    resP[i] = res+i-1;
}
```

should be:

```
for(int i=0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
    resP[i] = res+i;
}
```

or

```
for(int i=0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
    resP[i] = &res[i];
}
```

Comment: actually, `int i;` then `for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)` i was always told "don't declare the `int` inside the loop"

Comment: why not? I was told the opposite

Comment: To me, this should rather be noted just as a comment, simply because the question isn't this. Fine, this will help OP, but since this isn't the question, you could help from a comment. Voted up anyway, though I'm not sure why I did.

Comment: like I said, I can't change the function signature

Comment: OP's not allowed to change apply function

Comment: hmmm... then I guess the problem is somewhere else, although  I can't figure out where. thanx anyway

Comment: Did you include the header that actually contains the function prototype for `apply()`?